# Logical Equivalence of Wffs in Sentence, Predicate Logic using Tables, Interpretations Resp.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

just curious if there is a  formal name for the results that:

a) Two wffs in Sentence Logic are equivalent iff their truth tables are equal , as binary functions of {T,F}

b) Two wffs A,B in Predicate logic are equivalent when : I is an interpretation for A iff I is an interpretation for B.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with two statements being equivalent?

Comment: When we can find a derivation/proof  of one from he other, e.g., $P \rightarrow Q $ I equivalent to $-P \/ Q$ basically, P,Q are equivalent whenever P iff Q holds.

Comment: In sentential logic it's just another way of writing the completeness theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that [see [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA88), page 88] :

> $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are *logically equivalent* ($\varphi \equiv \psi$) iff $\varphi \vDash \psi$ and $\psi \vDash \varphi$,

where :

> Let $\Gamma$ be a set of wffs, $\varphi$ a wff. Then $\Gamma$ *logically implies* $\varphi$, written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, iff for **every** structure $\mathfrak A$ for the language and every function $s : V \to |\mathfrak A|$ such that $\mathfrak A$ satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ with $s$, $\mathfrak A$ also satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

We have that $\varphi \equiv \psi$ **iff** $\vDash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ (where : $\leftrightarrow$ is the *bi-conditional* connective).

---

*Note*

A *structure* $\mathfrak A$ for a first-order language, sometimes called an *interpretation*, is

> a function whose domain is the set of symbols of the language and such that
>
> > 1. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to the quantifier symbol ∀ a nonempty set $|\mathfrak A|$ called the *universe* (or domain) of $\mathfrak A$.
> > 2. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to each $n$-place predicate symbol $P$ an $n$-ary relation $P^A ⊆ |\mathfrak A|^n$, i.e., $P^A$ is a set of $n$-tuples of members of the universe.
> > 3. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to each constant symbol $c$ a member $c^A$ of the universe $|\mathfrak A|$.
> > 4. $\mathfrak A$ assigns to each $n$-place function symbol $f$ an $n$-ary operation $f^A$ on $|\mathfrak A|$, i.e., $f^A : |\mathfrak A|^n \to |\mathfrak A|$.

Comment: Thanks, +1 , is there a name for this result?

Comment: @gary - they are the general definitions of : *logical implication* and *logical equivalence*. For *propositional calculus*, they coincide with the usual definition in terms of *truth valuations*, implemented through the truth-table algorithm.

Comment: Can we extend this to truth trees, I guess, using interpretations?